# Missing verification controller in laravel

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.7 they have included a verification controller as part of email verification. I recently updated my application to 5.7, however,I cannot find the controller in that `Http/Controllers/Auth/Directory`.

I've already tried running the command PHP artisan `make:auth` but no controller was made when running this command.

Does anyone know where the controller could be or how I could generate one?

Thanks

Link: to authentication page Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fetch it from GitHub:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/VerificationController.php

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: 404 - Page not found.

Comment: All authentication logic is being moved to Laravel Fortify: https://github.com/laravel/fortify/blob/master/src/Http/Controllers/VerifyEmailController.php